# Manually creating a object list on Mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, model

I'm creating a Schedule Manager application using node.JS + Express + Mongoose and I'm trying to search for appointments on a specific day and location. If no appointments were found I want to create blank appointments between the start date and end date for them to be ready when I need it.

**Question:**

Can I return my just created appointment objects somehow instead of calling `Appointments.find` again? If it's possible, what's the best way of doing this?

Example: I imagine something like creating a new array and add each object through the iteration.

Here's the code for my model:

```
Appointment.find(query)
    .exec()
    .then((appointments) => {
        if (appointments.length == 0) {
            Location.findById(locationId)
            .exec()
            .then((location) => {
                for (let j = location.available_time_start; j <= location.available_time_end; j += location.appointment_duration) {
                    var newAppointment = new Appointment();

                    newAppointment.start_date = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate(), j);
                    newAppointment.appointment_duration = location.appointment_duration;
                    newAppointment.location = location.id;
                    newAppointment.booked = false;
                    newAppointment.locked = false;

                    Appointment.createAppointment(newAppointment, function (err, appointment) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log(appointment.location + ' - ' + appointment.start_date);
                    });
                }

                // I WANT TO RETURN THE APPOINTMENTS HERE!
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error while creating appointments: " + err);
            });
        } else {
            // IT RETURNS AS EXPECTED WHEN PREVIOUSLY INCLUDED!
            callback(null, appointments);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error while searching for appointments: " + err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an Array and returning it through `callback` function after saving each appointment:

```
                let newAppointments = Array();

                for (let j = location.available_time_start; j <= location.available_time_end; j += location.appointment_duration) {
                    let newAppointment = new Appointment();

                    newAppointment.start_date = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate(), j);
                    newAppointment.appointment_duration = location.appointment_duration;
                    newAppointment.location = location.id;
                    newAppointment.booked = false;
                    newAppointment.locked = false;

                    newAppointments.push(newAppointment);
                    newAppointment.save()
                    .then((appointment) => {
                        console.log(appointment.location + ' - ' + appointment.start_date);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log("Error while creating appointments: " + err);
                    })
                }

                callback(null, newAppointments);
```